# android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException

Tags: java, android

I have defined target SDK Version 31. I only get this error on Android 12 devices. There are lots of crashes.

Service can be a little overworked. It is reading data from the database. Shows notifications under appropriate conditions. I am using **Handler** and **Runnable** in some places.

How can I fix this or at least find a way to ignore it?

```
android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException (ActivityThread.java:2143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900 (ActivityThread.java:310)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2372)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Having the same issue with Samsung devices on Android 12. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. The problematic devices are 100% Samsung devices on Android 12.

Comment: Seeing this issue on Pixel 4a too, also Android 12

Comment: have a similar issue, also 100% Samsung with Android 12

Comment: Having the same issue with all devices on Android 12. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any luck with the solution? @MahmutK.

Comment: In my case it was simply an exception in the foreground service's 'onStartCommand' that happened along the way before 'startService' was called.